# Codeception\Test\Test::run(?\Framework\TestResult $result = NULL) must be compatible with

Tags: phpunit, php-7, codeception

PHP v7.2.3
PHP Unit 8.2.3
Codeception 3.0.2

When I try to run tests I get the following error:

> Declaration of
>   Codeception\Test\Test::run(?PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult $result =
>   NULL) must be compatible with
>   PHPUnit\Framework\Test::run(?PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult $result =
>   NULL): PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult in
>   /var/com/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Test/Test.php
>   on line 18

When I look at the definition of PHPUnit\Framework\Test::run I see it specifies a return type but Codeception\Test\Test::run does not and this would appear to be the problem.

I've checked back through the version history of both of these files in the respective git repos and it seem these files have been this way for many versions.

After much searching it doesn't seem anyone else has posted the issue which makes me think I'm missing some key insight.

Any light shed on this issue would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The PHP error message - and you question confirms it -  shows that Codeception 3.0.2 is incompatible with PHP Unit 8.2.3. I'm not that much into it, but a first guess would be that Codeception - even if it has Phpunit as a dependency - does not do adequate version pinning for Phpunit (not saying that Codeception is bad, I guess it's a certain fine tool, version pinning is just normally not often focused on in the meaning that releases actually pin-point the for the release expected and confirmed stable exact versions). Please feel free to comment.

Comment: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/5031

Comment: @hakre Yeah it's what I thought at first - so I checked the version history, return type is specified for the run function from phpunit 7 onwards 6.5.14 being the last version without. However, this article leads me to believe that v3 of codeception supports phpunit 7 onwards
https://codeception.com/04-24-2019/codeception-3.0.html

Comment: @Naktibalda I see your test is passing with the latest versions, thanks for the link but could you explain how these 2 functions can have different return type definitions and still work. It would help with troubleshooting. Thanks

Comment: Probably it works when https://github.com/Codeception/phpunit-wrapper/blob/8.0/src/phpunit7-interfaces.php is loaded before PHPUnit\Framework\Test from phpunit.

Comment: This might be bug material then. Check if a Github issue exists for the error message in Codeception and report it otherwise. The ref given by @Naktibalda also shows some devs might be aware of this already. Maybe Codeception is for a PHP version w/o return types (pre PHP 7.0, e.g. for backwards compatibility reasons).

Comment: Update on the ticket: This happens when project has dependency on another library which tries to be compatible with multiple major versions of PHPUnit.

Comment: @Naktibalda Thanks. In then end I decided to take a fresh copy of symfony but this time v4 instead of 3.4 based on your working symfony demo and all working ok! I had copied some composer configs from a previous 3.4 app so likely something in that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jfxninja: Please formulate an answer to your own question (this is perfectly fine), you can even accept it as the answer later on (for own answers, it takes a period of time until this is possible, but not too long, it's just that others can also answer still). Formulating a _real_ answer is much better as just leave the question with the comments (which are also already insighful, but it's also quite some trouble-shooting noise. --- I guess the Phpunit compat layer in Symfony4 does not come with that many defects the previous had ... .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end a fresh install of Symfony latest version and Codeception presented a working solution.

Since this was initially a port from another symfony 3 application (with an older version of codeception) it's likely that there was a misconfig or incompatible package.

The other possible cause which occurred to me later is that the cli for codeception in previous versions of symfony was run from a general bin directory 'bin/codecept' and now we run directly from 'vendor/bin/codecept' its possible that my CI script was referencing an outdated cli.